# Cannot access children in after_create method in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

In my app I have bookings and passengers where one booking has many passengers.

After creating a new booking I want to send a notification to all passengers, so in my Booking model I have:

```
after_create :send_notification

def send_notification
  self.passengers.each do |passenger|
    #DO STUFF
  end
end
```

This does not do anything and if I try

```
puts(self.passengers.count)
```

it returns 0.

When I user `after_save` everything works, so I assume that after_create it created the parent but not the children yet.

Problem is that I can't use `after_save` because this trigger also after updating.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add condition for `after_save`:

```
after_save :send_notification, if: :id_changed?
# or :id_previously_changed? I don't remember if in after_save you can access dirty attributes
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your callback to this:

```
after_save :send_notification, on: :create
```

So that your callback will fire after saving instead of creating the object, but will *only* occur when it's first created.